# splash screens not showing titanium appcelerator 5.2.2GA

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've added all the default files to assets/iphone but it keeps showing a small square image when loading the app.

- Default-568h@2x.png
- Default-667h@2x.png
- Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png
- Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png
- Default@2x.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems storyboard launch screen is enabled for your app. You can either disable it or add the **LaunchLogo** image set to the asset catalog.

Details [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_5.2.0_Release_Note-section-46245011_TitaniumSDK5.2.0ReleaseNote-Storyboard-basedLaunchScreen)

It's a new feature starting SDK 5.2.0. It's similar to Android's 9 patch, so that you don't have to have one launch image for each screen size.

Comment: Indeed. New projects have Storyboard Launch Files enabled by default. Aso see http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/titanium-5-2-0-launch-files-ipad-pro-slide-over-and-split-view/

Answer (score -1):

Try generate splash screens using this awesome tool  `ticons` [enter link description here](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl)

Comment: That's not the issue. New projects default to use a Storyboard Launch File.